# One more an incorrect result of FunctionAnalytic

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Studying a new in 12.2 command `FunctionAnalytic`, I execute

```
FunctionAnalytic[{Sqrt[z],Abs[z] >= 1/2 && Abs[z] <= 3/2 && Im[z] >= 0}, z,Complexes]
```

> `False`

Unfortunately, the obtained result is not correct. Let us look in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function)

> A function $f$ defined on some subset of the real line is said to be real analytic at a point
> $x$ if there is a neighborhood $D$ of $x$ on which $f$ is real analytic.
> The definition of a complex analytic function is obtained by replacing, in the definitions above, "real" with "complex" and "real line"
> with "complex plane". A function is complex analytic if and only if it is holomorphic i.e. it is complex differentiable.
> For this reason the terms "holomorphic" and "analytic" are often used interchangeably for such functions.[1]

and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_function) seconds it in the "Analytic continuation and Riemann surfaces" section.

It's clear that an analytic function $r e^{i\phi} \mapsto r^{\frac 1 2} e^{i \frac \phi 2}$ can be analytically extended
from the set $\{re^{i\phi}: r\ge \frac 1 2, r \le \frac 3 2 , \phi \ge 0, \phi \le \pi\}$ to the domain
$\{re^{i\phi}: r > \frac 1 4, r < \frac 5 2 , \phi > - \frac \pi 4, \phi < \pi + \frac \pi 4\}$
(It's enough to verify Cauchy-Riemann equations to this end.).
Also see [Weisstein, Eric W. "Analytic Continuation" From MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticContinuation.html)
with a nice animation in the attaced nb file.

Is there a workaround here and in other similar cases? If there does not exist a one, then it would be better if `FunctionAnalytic`
returned the input in such cases.

Comment: I think it's because MMA has chosen the brunch cut of `Sqrt[z]` to be the minus real axis, and your region just touches the brunch cut so that MMA cannot find a larger open set containing it. Consider the examples `FunctionAnalytic[{Sqrt[z],Arg@z<Pi&&z!=0},z,Complexes]
FunctionAnalytic[{Sqrt[z],Arg@z<=Pi&&z!=0},z,Complexes]`, they will return `True` and `False`.